# How to pass named parameters from airflow dag to a databricks spark python task?

Tags: airflow, databricks

My goal is to initiate a databricks task programmatically via airflow with a named parameter, however while the task is triggered successfully, the parameter was not passed; instead I receive this error message: com.databricks.dbutils_v1.InputWidgetNotDefined: No input widget named name is defined

The output of the job should be "Hello <Name>!" where name is the parameter.

This is the source code for the databricks job:

```
value = dbutils.widgets.get("name")
print(f"Hello {value}!")
```

And this is the source code for the airflow DAG:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.databricks.operators.databricks import DatabricksSubmitRunOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

import json

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow'
}

with DAG('databricks_dag',
    start_date = days_ago(2),
    schedule_interval = None,
    default_args = default_args
) as dag:

opr_run_now1 = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id = 'run_now_1',
    json={
        "existing_cluster_id": "1234-56789-10112234",
        "spark_python_task": {
            "python_file": "/Repos/username/ace-databricks-jobs/hello.py",
            "parameters": json.dumps({
                "name": "Peter Pan",
            }),
        }
    },
    databricks_conn_id='conn-databricks',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass widget parameters, you should provide them in `notebook_params` not `spark_python_task`:

```py
opr_run_now1 = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id = 'run_now_1',
    json={
        "existing_cluster_id": "1234-56789-10112234",
        "spark_python_task": {
            "python_file": "/Repos/username/ace-databricks-jobs/hello.py",
        },
        "notebook_params": {
            "name": "Peter Pan"
        }
    },
    databricks_conn_id='conn-databricks',
)
```